# Combining two tables and get selected output matching the substring of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 
root@23.73.134.107:~# s "select ecor from rm_ecors" | head

```
 ecor
-----
1,111
5,890
7,164
5,083
4,935
4,064
1,033
6,498
```

root@23.73.134.107:~# s "select key from rm_nie_configreader_details" | head -10

### key

```
 nieMultilink.ecor5107
 nieMultilink.ecor5062
 nieMultilink.ecor5569
 nieMultilink.ecor6720
nieMultiVlink.link1110
 nieMultilink.ecor6427
 nieMultilink.ecor7257
 nieMultilink.ecor1910
```

I want to make a query such that , I want ecors from the first table which are not in second tables substring.

I am using this query, which is not working.

root@23.73.134.107:~# s "select * from rm_ecors where ecor not like  %(select key from rm_nie_configreader_details)% " 
error: syntax error on line 1 at '%'

Any thought will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one using an `outer join` with a `null` check:

```
select *
from rm_ecors e 
    left join rm_nie_configreader_details n on e.ecor like concat('%',n.key,'%')
where n.key is null
```